# PHP - How to search array for same value pair

Tags: php

I have an array like the below which comes from my db.  It holds currency pairs (eg. USD to AUD dollars, etc).

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [xrate_amount] => 1
        [xrate_from] => AUD
        [xrate_to] => GBP
        [xrate_date] => 2020-12-05 01:50:29
        [xrate_rate] => 0.0000000000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [xrate_amount] => 1
        [xrate_from] => BRL
        [xrate_to] => AUD
        [xrate_date] => 2020-12-05 02:16:29
        [xrate_rate] => 0.0000000000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [xrate_amount] => 1
        [xrate_from] => JPY
        [xrate_to] => AUD
        [xrate_date] => 2020-05-12 00:00:00
        [xrate_rate] => 0.0139800000
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [xrate_amount] => 1
        [xrate_from] => JPY
        [xrate_to] => CAD
        [xrate_date] => 2020-05-12 00:00:00
        [xrate_rate] => 0.0128100000
```

I am trying to insert a new currency pair into my db only if the currency pair doesn't already exist in the db.  I am trying to write a function that receives $xrate_from and $xrate_to from a form and then search the above array called $inserted_currency (comes from db actually) and returns TRUE is the pair already exists (btw JPY CAD is different than CAD JPY).

I am totally stumped and would appreciated any guidance.

Comment: I would do that on the database level : adding a unique key on the column pair xrate_from, xrate_to. Then you can add items in it with `INSERT IGNORE INTO` or `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make two one-dimensional arrays for those columns that you need to compare in the end. Then find the keys of the two values in those arrays and make sure it's the same.

```
public function pairExists($yourXRateFromValueFromform, $yourXRateToValueFromform, $yourArray): bool
{
   return array_search($yourXRateFromValueFromform, array_column($yourArray, 'xrate_from')) === array_search($yourXRateToValueFromform, array_column($yourArray, 'xrate_to'))
}
```

Comment: Add some description of how you do that

Comment: No problem on that it is much prettier now

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Check below

```
<?php

function exchangeRateExists($allPairs, $xrate_from, $xrate_to) {
    return (bool)array_filter($allPairs, function($pair) use ($xrate_from, $xrate_to){
        return $pair['xrate_from'] == $xrate_from && $pair['xrate_to'] == $xrate_to;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function existsxratepair($xrateFrom,$xrateTo, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['xrate_from'] == $xrateFrom && $val['xrate_to'] == $xrateTo) {
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

 }
 // call the function
 existsxratepair('JPY','CAD',$array);
```

with this code you can find the values are exists or not.

you can also check the values in database with use of query like

```
SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE xrate_from = 'yourValue' AND xrate_to = 'yourValue'
```

then count result if it return more then 0 row it exist in database